# pyminiaudio EOFError input()

Tags: python, docker, raspberry-pi, icecast

I am trying to run a python script which plays an Icecast steam using Docker. But whenever I run my docker image it shows EOFError. The only reason I am using docker is to have auto restart functionality if my application closes unexpectedly (system crash). Although alternate solutions other than docker are welcome.

```
debian@raspberrypi:~/app $ docker image build -t infinite .
debian@raspberrypi:~/app $ docker run infinite
Connected to internet stream, audio format: MP3
Station name:  myStation Main Stream
Station genre:  None
Press <enter> to quit playing.

Stream title:  SoundHelix - Unknown
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/debian/app/test.py", line 21, in <module>
    input()
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

test.py

```
import miniaudio

def title_printer(client: miniaudio.IceCastClient, new_title: str) -> None:
    print("Stream title: ", new_title)

with miniaudio.IceCastClient("http://localhost:8000/stream3",
        update_stream_title=title_printer) as source:
    print("Connected to internet stream, audio format:", source.audio_format.name)
    print("Station name: ", source.station_name)
    print("Station genre: ", source.station_genre)
    print("Press <enter> to quit playing.\n")
    stream = miniaudio.stream_any(source, source.audio_format)
    with miniaudio.PlaybackDevice() as device:
        device.start(stream)
        input()
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:latest

LABEL Maintainer="John Doe"

WORKDIR /home/debian/app

COPY test.py ./

RUN pip install miniaudio

CMD ["python", "test.py"]
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with python but for docker I'd say the problem is here: `http://localhost:8000/stream3`. That might work on host but not inside a container. So you should change `localhost` with something outside the container I guess

Comment: `input()` may needs direct access to `console`/`terminal` but docker may run it without direct access to `console`/`terminal` and it may have problem to wait for user's data. Maybe better use `while True: time.sleep(1)`. OR check in documentation if `device` has some function to wait for the end of stream.

Comment: duplicated question suggests to run docket with `-t` to allocate a pseudo terminal.